# how to give some hover in <area> tag with css/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my code

```css
.x1:hover{
   background-color: rgb(30, 173, 104);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <style media="screen">
  .x1:hover{
   background-color: rgb(30, 173, 104);
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->

<img src="imgmap.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_self" alt="floor3" title="floor3" href="" coords="113,228,369,107,488,168,488,210,371,167,244,212,114,259,113,247,113,238" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="floor2" title="floor2" href="" coords="488,239,491,286,371,264,113,323,114,285,371,210,434,225" shape="poly">
    <area target="_self" alt="floor1" title="floor1" href="" coords="376,298,489,314,490,357,375,358,115,367,115,339" shape="poly">
    <area class="x1" target="" id="x1" alt="rooftop" title="rooftop" href="" coords="372,44,488,115,488,136,372,69,125,187,123,169" shape="poly" onmouseover=" document.map.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; " onmouseout="x1.style.backgroundColor='transparent';"> document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        </map>


    </body>
    </html>
```

how to add hover in area tag ? , anyone can help me ?

Answer (score -1):

you could try with (every tag area will have this css):

```
area:hover{
your css here
...
}
```